# Log-normal ratio implies numerator/denominator are log-normal

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two positive random variables defined over $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$. We know that if they are both log-normal then the random variable $Z$ defined as:
$$Z:=\ln\frac{X}{Y}$$
is normally distributed.

**Is the converse true?** Namely if $Z$ is a normal variable defined as above, can we conclude $X,Y$ are both log-normal? Equivalently, if the ratio $X/Y$ is log-normal, does it imply $X,Y$ are so too?

Comment: Definitely not, because you make no assumptions about how $X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed.  So just take $Z$ and *independently* of it choose $Y$ to have any positive distribution you like and *define* $X=Ye^Z.$ If you intend that $X$ and $Y$ be independent, then please edit your post to indicate that.

Comment: You may as well remove the **log**normal part, by considering $V=\log(X), W=\log(Y)$ and so ask about $Z=V-W$ and normal distributions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent positive variables and $X/Y$ is lognormal, then $\ln(X/Y)=\ln X +(- \ln Y)$ is normal. So by [Cramer’s decomposition theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_decomposition_theorem) both $\ln X$ and $-\ln Y$ are normal, and $X$ and $Y$ must be lognormal.